# trying to put a green overlay and title to the example image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image have green overlay and a title inside the image itself at the same time while trying to be responsive all at the same time, i have tried everything and i just cant make it work.

```css
.headline-picture{
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: 
  linear-gradient(
   rgba(10, 158, 0, 0.5),
   rgba(10, 158, 0, 0.5)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="article-headline">
  <img class="headline-picture" src="example image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand the requirement... Have a look at the below snippet. Is this what you were looking for?

I've put the overlay as a separate element and is `position:absolute`.

```css
.article-headline {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.headline-picture {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-headline">
  <img class="headline-picture" src="https://placekitten.com/640/360">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this is almost perfect, for some reason it shows the images width, but not the height.

Comment: @JacobAnderson i've amended my answer, is that any better?

Comment: still doing the same thing the image is still not showing height

Comment: @JacobAnderson No problem :-)

Comment: @JacobAnderson If this is the correct answer accept it as a valid answer please :-)